# Python ImportError loading oauth2_provider on Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: oauth-2.0

I am trying to deploy oauth2 and oauth2-provider on my Python/Django web server, which is deployed on Ubuntu using Amazon Web Services (EC2 and Elastic Beanstalk).

When I run the web server locally, all works fine.
When I tar all of the files and transfer them to the EC2 instance, I successfully loaded the

Following are the installed apps from my settings.py file:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'oauth2_provider',
    'corsheaders',
    'consentrecords',
    'custom_user',
    'monitor',
)
```

Here are the commands I used to install the various tools needed for oauth2 (after ensuring that the virtualenv was properly set up):

```
sudo apt-get install python3-oauthlib
pip3 install django-cors-headers
pip3 install django-oauth-toolkit
pip3 install django-oauth2-provider
```

When I specify python3 manage.py runserver on the EC2 instance, it launches a local web server properly, which means to me that the settings.py file has been read properly.

However, when I deploy the instance to Elastic Beanstalk (using the command eb deploy), The web server has an internal error. The following comes from the logs:

```
mod_wsgi (pid=6880): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/opt/python/current/app/prod/consentrecords/consentrecords/wsgi.py'.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/python/current/app/prod/consentrecords/consentrecords/wsgi.py", line 21, in <module>
    application = get_wsgi_application()
  File "/opt/python/run/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 14, in get_wsgi_application
    django.setup()
  File "/opt/python/run/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 18, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/opt/python/run/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 85, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "/opt/python/run/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 86, in create
    module = import_module(entry)
  File "/opt/python/run/baselinenv/lib64/python3.4/importlib/__init__.py", line 109, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2254, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2237, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2224, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  ImportError: No module named 'oauth2_provider'
```

I also tried running python3 on the EC2 instance and give the command "import oauth2_provider". The command produced no error and appeared to load the module.

Why would this work on my local system and seem to load properly on the EC2 instance, but not the Elastic Beanstalk instance?

Answer (score 0):

I discovered that this was the first time I needed to incorporate site-packages.

I solved the problem by editing the PYTHONPATH in the .ebextensions/01-django_eb.config file to include the site-packages directory that contained oauth2-provider.

Following is the .config file:

```
option_settings:   "aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment":
    DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE: "consentrecords.settings"
    PYTHONPATH: "/opt/python/current/app/prod/consentrecords:/opt/python/current/app/prod/consentrecords/consentrecords:<b>/opt/python/current/app/prod/lib/python3.4/site-packages:$PYTHONPATH" "aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python":
    WSGIPath: "prod/consentrecords/consentrecords/wsgi.py"   "aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python:staticfiles":
    "/static/": "prod/consentrecords/static/"
```

Comment: Michael I am having the same issue, I am totally new on Django could you please explain a little more?

Comment: This only applies to elastic beanstalk deployments. Elastic Beanstalk allows a configuration file to be read during deployment that sets up environment variables for the EB system.Thus, my fix was to correctly set up the PYTHONPATH environment variable to include the path to the oauth2 modules.